# If statement being ignored in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

The source code I have written (Mind you, I am a new-learner so I am currently working my way through a book to teach myself).

Everything seems to work, but the code seems to ignore the statement "if (fahrenheit >= 80). It works with the first statement parameters, but will jump to the else condition for all numbers above 79 and below 50, rather than outputting different text for values above 80.

Advice?

```
#include <iostream>

float convert(float);

int main()
{
    float fahrenheit;
    float celsius;

    std::cout << "Please enter the temperature in Celsius: ";
    std::cin >> celsius;
    fahrenheit = convert(celsius);
    std::cout << "\nThe temperature in Fahrenheit is: " << fahrenheit << "\n";


if ((fahrenheit <= 79) && (fahrenheit >= 50))
{
    if (fahrenheit >= 80)
    {
        std::cout << "\n What a hot day!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "\n What a nice day!\n";
}
    else
        std::cout << "\n It's freezing!\n";

    return 0;
}   

float convert(float celsius)
{
    float fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9) / 5) +32;
    return fahrenheit;
}
```

Comment: Just note that `if`s are never straight up ignored. If it's only going to the `else`, that means that the condition is false.

Comment: The statement `fahrenheit >= 80` cannot be true if both `fahrenheit <= 79` and `fahrenheit >= 50` are true.

Comment: Why did you put in a logic check fof fahrenheit to be greater than 80 inside a if case where fahrenheit is greater than 50 and less than 79? Hint: move the check outside of the if case...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is EXACTLY why unit testing was invented.  The problem is your logic. Take a closer look, that code will never be hit.

Answer (score 3):

The `if (fahrenheit >= 80)` statement isn't ignored, it's simply impossible for it to ever be true. As written, that clause is only checked if both `fahrenheit <= 79` and `fahrenheit >= 50` are true. How can `fahrenheit` be greater or equal to 80 if it must be between 50 and 79 inclusive?

You probably meant this:

```
if ((fahrenheit <= 79) && (fahrenheit >= 50))
{
    std::cout << "\n What a nice day!\n";
} else if (fahrenheit >= 80)
{
    std::cout << "\n What a hot day!\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This fixed the issue. Nice to know someone out there has some answers for this newbie.

Comment: Glad to help! If your question is answered then click the checkmark next to the answer to mark that as the correct answer. That way others will know you don't need any more help.